# Simple method to determine the sign of the permutation $x \rightarrow x^{-1}$ on a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $f: G\rightarrow G$ be the map defined by $f(x) = x^{-1}$.

> Is there a simple method to determine the sign of the permutation $f$?

The motivation is as follows(I don't think it's necessary to state it, but some users tend to vote to close a question without motivation).

Let $K/k$ be a finite Galois extension, $G$ its Galois group.
One of the proofs of the normal basis theorem uses the determinant $det (x_{\sigma\tau^{-1}})$, where we assign a variable $x_{\sigma}$ to each $\sigma \in G$.
I wonder what is the difference between $det(x_{\sigma\tau^{-1}})$ and $det(x_{\sigma\tau})$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of transpositions is half the number of elements after you discard the fixed points.  So let n be the number of involutions in G.  If |G|-n-1 is congruent to 2 mod 4, then inversion is an odd permutation.  Otherwise, |G|-n-1 is congruent to 0 mod 4, and inversion is even.

This reduces the question to counting involutions, which might or might not be a reasonable task depending on the group.

Comment: *This reduces the question to counting involutions, which might or might not be a reasonable task depending on the group.* Do you know a non-trivial example in which counting involutions is easy? Of course, a group of odd order is such one.